# Need assistance to understand python code - I am very beginner in Python

Tags: python, algorithm

There's this algo question as below and I could find a solution for it online which looks a lot like what I came up with but I am not able to understand the multiple of 3 and 5 part.

The question is "Write a program that outputs the string representation of numbers from 1 to n. But for multiples of three it should output “Fizz” instead of the number and for the multiples of five output “Buzz”. For numbers which are multiples of both three and five output “FizzBuzz”."

This is solution of google:

```
def fizzBuzz(n):
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        return ['Fizz' * (not i % 3) + 'Buzz' * (not i % 5) or str(i) for i in range(1, n+1)]
```

This is what I am trying to do for a similar problem:

```
def nicFizzbuzz(n):
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        #print(i)
        if ( not i % 3):
            print('Fizz')
        elif(not i % 5):
            print('Buzz')
        elif(not i % 3) and (not i % 5):
            print("FizzBuzz")
        else:
            print(i)
```

Can someone explain where am I going wrong?

Comment: It'd be easier to help if you format your code the right way!

Comment: Why do you think you are doing something wrong?

Comment: It's because i am not getting the right output, this is what i get
1
2
Fizz
4
Buzz
Fizz
7
8
Fizz
Buzz
11
Fizz
13
14
Fizz
It should be FizzBuzz for 15 but its just Fizz, just a further note here "n=15"

Comment: I ran your code, and it gives the right answer. Unless, of course, you want all numbers to be on the same line.

Comment: I don't mind them being in same line, it doesn't work and print right keyword for number that are multiple of 3 and 5 both

Comment: FYI, in the googled answer, there's no need for the first `for` loop. The loop is done in the generator.

Comment: In the googled answer, the part you describe as "the multiples of 3 and 5 part" isn't quite that.  `not i % 3` gives a boolean result (i.e., when used as a number, it's 0 or 1).  `'Fizz' * 1` is `'Fizz'`, while  `'Fizz' * 0` is `''` (the empty string); the `'Buzz'` part works similarly.  As @charli says, the outer `for` loop is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

You must write 3 and 5's case first.

```
def nicFizzbuzz(n):
  for i in range(1,n+1):
    #print(i)
    if(not i % 3) and (not i % 5):
      print("FizzBuzz")
    elif ( not i % 3):
        print('Fizz')
    elif(not i % 5):
        print('Buzz')
    else:
        print(i)
```

Comment: thanks it seem to give out right expected result, if not much trouble can i ask how the specifying case in this manner makes a difference?

Comment: As @Dinesh.hmn mentioned, when FizzBuzz's number(e.g. 15) come, your code print `Fizz` and go next number because the number is also multiple of 3. So, you have to bring your FizzBuzz case at first. Do you get my point? Sorry for my poor explanation.

Comment: Here is additional explanation. One `if statement` get just only one result. You write 4 options(`not i % 3`, `not i % 5`, `not i % 3 and not i % 5` and else).  If your statement got `true`, evaluation in `if statement` ends and goes next number on for loop.

Comment: My pleasure! Anyway, if your question was resolved, I recommend you accept the answer and close the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are evaluating the conditions wrong. Lets assume that n is from 1 to 20. You expect to see "FizzBuzz" printed at 15. But from your function, you are evaluating first that 15 is divisible by 3, which is true. The function does not evaluate the rest of the conditions and moves to 16.

A simple workaround would be to move the 3 and 5 divisibility condition to be on the top like

```
def nicFizzbuzz(n):
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        if(not i % 3) and (not i % 5):
            print("FizzBuzz")  
        elif ( not i % 3):
            print('Fizz')
        elif(not i % 5):
            print('Buzz')
        else:
            print(i)

n = 20

nicFizzbuzz(n)
```

and this results in

> 1 2 Fizz 4 Buzz Fizz 7 8 Fizz Buzz 11 Fizz 13 14 FizzBuzz 16 17 Fizz
>   19 Buzz

Comment: thanks it seem to give out right expected result, if not much trouble can i ask how the specifying case in this manner makes a difference?

Comment: In an if-else system of conditions, when a first "if" is satisfied, the loop never checks the other conditions. The code expects that if one "if" condition is true, the second one will be false. Its more like, is today a rainy day? If yes, it can never be no also at the same time. So if today is a rainy day, why check if today is not a rainy day?

Answer (score 0):

Moving the test for values divisible by both 3 and 5 above the other tests is a good way to get the correct result, but I'd like to add another way to do this.
Instead of doing a test for each combination separately but *not* exclusively.  Rather than using `elif`, this version accumulates the value to print.

```
def nicFizzbuzz(n):
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        val = ''
        if (not i % 3):
            val += 'Fizz'
        if (not i % 5):
            val += 'Buzz'
        print(val or i)
```